# Try_files in 2 different locations

Tags: nginx

I have production (site.com) and development (dev.site.com) sites, located on the same server. I'm trying to configure Nginx for the following case:

All images stored only on production. For example, `/var/www/site.com/html/images`. I can create an alias for all images on development server link to production, and `/var/www/dev.site.com/html/images/img.jpg` will get image from `/var/www/site.com/html/images/img.jpg`.

But if developer upload image for development purposes, this link will be broken, because this image exists only in development images folder.

Nginx `try_files` is a good for this, but I can't configure it correctly.

My rule is:

```
location ^~ /images/ {
    try_files $uri /var/www/site.com/html/images/$uri =404;
}
```

but it's won't work. What's wrong in this?

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? One of your paths has a `/html/` component.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `try_files` directive accepts *file* parameters which look like URIs. The pathname of the file is constructed by concatenating the value of the `root` directive with the value of the *file* parameter.

With the two pathnames you are using (`/var/www/site.com/html/images/img.jpg` and `/var/www/dev.site.com/html/images/img.jpg`), the common part is `/var/www`.

The variable `$uri` will be set to `/images/img.jpg`, so the *file* parameter just needs to provide the missing pieces.

For example:

```
location ^~ /images/ {
    root /var/www;
    try_files /site.com/html$uri /dev.site.com/html$uri =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.